# Corda - use of other messaging broker?

Tags: corda

Using Corda v3.1.

From the [node configuration docs](https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html) :

`messagingServerAddress: the address of the ArtemisMQ broker instance. If not provided the node will run one locally`

Are there any examples of a setup where nodes are using another broker for messaging instead of a local Artemis instance?

Comment: Hey Matthieu, what's the use-case here? I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: No use case in particular so far, was just wondering if there was any option to reuse existing message infrastructures which are often already present

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate Artemis broker is not currently recommended. The Corda team is still doing work to fully support this configuration setting.

Note also that it is not currently possible to use a message broker other than Artemis with Corda. This feature is desirable but not a current priority, and implementing it makes the work on high availability and disaster recovery more difficult. One issue is that AMQP provides no `queueCreation` primitive. So queue creation must be managed on a per-broker basis, even if all the brokers support AMQP.